# AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent never called

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I use spring-boot 2.6.8 with spring security

When user don't enter correct information, i would like to do an operation.
So I created this class.

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationFailureEventListener implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent {

    private LoginAttemptService loginAttemptService;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent e) {

        WebAuthenticationDetails auth = (WebAuthenticationDetails) e.getAuthentication().getDetails();

        loginAttemptService.loginFailed(e.getAuthentication().getName(), auth.getRemoteAddress());
    }

}
```

If a user enter a bad password, this event is never called

Edit

For the security, I have this

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {    
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationEventPublisher authenticationEventPublisher;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler customAuthenticationSuccessHandler;


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationEventPublisher(authenticationEventPublisher).userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The events are not published out of the box. You need to also declare an `AuthenticationEventPublisher` with code like this:

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationEventPublisher authenticationEventPublisher(
    ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher
) {
  return new DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher(applicationEventPublisher);
}
```

Please also have a look at this part of the reference documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/events.html